# apache+php+mysql автоматическое создание виртуальных хостов?

Tags: apache, virtual-hosts, php, localhost, сервер

Как сделать так чтобы не править каждый раз руками `httpd.conf`+`hosts`, а чтобы виртуальные хосты автоматически создавались (как в `Denwer` напр.)? Система `WinXP Home`.

`п.с.` своя сборка `apache`+`php`+`mysql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Вопрос на руткод</sup>

Вот очень хорошая [статья на эту тему](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129900/). Статья про линукс, но и для винды это всё тоже можно соорудить.

Главным действующим лицом является `mod_vhost_alias`.

> Модуль организует динамическое создание виртуальных хостов на основе запрошенного доменного имени и не требует внесения изменений в конфигурационные файлы сервера при создании новых виртуальных хостов

Если вам повезло с роутером, и на нём есть что-то вроде `DD-WRT`, то bind можно не устанавливать, а ограничиться настройкой DNS-зоны на роутере. Если же не повезло, вот [тут есть статья](http://verhoum.livejournal.com/8736.html) про настройку bind на XP.

Comment: у меня локальный сервер. Пожалуйста, `никаких Linux` (я вижу много статей в гугле про линукс и почти совсем ничего на XP).

Comment: `mod_vhost_alias` настраивается на винде абсолютно аналогично линуксу. Разве что пути к файлам и каталогам другие.

А настройка DNS сервера на XP приведена по ссылке.

Comment: ошибка: `[Sat Feb 09 17:57:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/LocalS/sites/home/_`

Answer (score 1):

можно так сделать

в .htaccess в DOCUMENT_ROOT дефолтного вхоста

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{HTTP_HOST}/ -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

и в DOCUMENT_ROOT такое дерево

```
mysite.com/
mysite2.com/
```

итд

но это очень грубое решение... из палаты №6

насчет непрописывания в hosts... тут все дело в том, что где-то вам надо прописать способ которым ваш локальный комп будет ссылаться на 127.0.0.1, как сказал [[@mantigatos](/users/5737/mantigatos)](/users/5737/mantigatos) dns сервер вам нужен.

Comment: так что будут все сайты ссылаться что ли?

Comment: eicto не понимая ваш реча.  
Вышеописанный способ сделает "типа vhostом" все домены, на которые придет запрос, к вашей рабочей станции, **и** для которых существует директория вида DOCROOT/HOSTNAME

Comment: вообще, я не понимаю сложности с копированием файла в sites.d директории конфига и исправлением там пары строчек.

Comment: Я вот по этой статье настраивал: http://habrahabr.ru/post/139792/ только так и не понял где именно прописать 127.0.0.1 чтобы ссылалось все куда надо.