# apache+php+mysql автоматическое создание виртуальных хостов?

Tags: apache, php, hosts, mysql

Как сделать так чтобы не править каждый раз руками `httpd.conf+hosts`, а чтобы виртуальные хосты автоматически создавались (как в Denwer напр.)? Система `WinXP Home`.

`п.с.` своя сборка `apache+php+mysql`.

Только не надо ссылок на создание Виртуальных Хостов под `Linux`.

После правок `httpd.conf`, в частности добавления вот этой настройки:

```
785: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>786:   RewriteEngine on787:   RewriteBase /788:   # Your rewrite rules go next789: </IfModule>
```

`Apache` перестал запускаться, ошибка запуска гласит:

```
C:\LocalS\apache\bin>httpd -wSyntax error on line 787 of C:/LocalS/apache/conf/httpd.conf:RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config filesNote the errors or messages above, and press the <ESC> key to exit.  0....C:\LocalS\apache\bin>
```

Настройки соединения:

[Скрин текущих Настроек Соединения](http://tau.rghost.ru/43667799/image.png)

`Обновился`: с 1-ой проблемой решилось все таким образом:

```
<Directory c:/LocalS/sites/home>    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks    AllowOverride All    Order deny,allow    Allow from all<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  RewriteEngine on  RewriteBase /  # Your rewrite rules go next</IfModule></Directory>
```

Теперь `apache` хотя бы запускается, все еще не пойму как создать автоматически виртуальный хост, в частности куда прописать в настройки соединения `127.0.0.1`?

**Обновление** : Не заходит на (лок.) сайты, ошибки в логах `apache` следующие:

```
[Sat Feb 09 16:59:35 2013] [warn] VirtualHost kohana.loc:80 overlaps with VirtualHost kohana.orm:80, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive[Sat Feb 09 16:59:35 2013] [warn] VirtualHost test.loc:80 overlaps with VirtualHost kohana.loc:80, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive[Sat Feb 09 16:59:35 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts[Sat Feb 09 16:59:35 2013] [notice] Child 1956: Child process is running[Sat Feb 09 16:59:35 2013] [notice] Child 1956: Acquired the start mutex.[Sat Feb 09 16:59:35 2013] [notice] Child 1956: Starting 64 worker threads.[Sat Feb 09 16:59:35 2013] [notice] Child 1956: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

`Обновление`: Поставил у всех существующих Виртуальных хостов `*:80`:

напр.

```
#kohana<VirtualHost *:80>ServerAdmin tolbasa@gmail.comServerName kohana.locDocumentRoot "C:/LocalS/sites/home/kohana.loc/www"ScriptAlias /cgi/ "C:/LocalS/Sites/home/kohana.loc/cgi/"ErrorLog C:/LocalS/sites/home/kohana.loc/error.logCustomLog C:/LocalS/sites/home/kohana.loc/access.log common</VirtualHost>
```

Увы, опять не могу попасть на сайт, теперь ошибка в логах самого сайта:

```
[Sat Feb 09 17:57:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/LocalS/sites/home/_
```

Что теперь делать?

Comment: Так, а теперь после всех этих манипуляций у меня `apace` запускается, но не запускаются локальные сайты.

Comment: Делал все как в статье указано, куча ошибок появилось.

Comment: Ну что, никто не знает что теперь? Что я мог не так настроить?

Comment: Ладно, все, разобрался. Без `*.local` было.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот аналогичная[*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/191412#191416) статья только про Windows: [Автоматизация создания виртуальных хостов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/139792/)

Comment: у меня локальный сервер.

Comment: там расплывчато написано где именно в конфиге `Acrylic` прописать `DNS`: http://codepaste.ru/13495/, куда именно прописать `8.8.8.8`?

Comment: и пардон, если я изменю `DNS` моего провайдера на 127.0.0.1 в `Wi-Fi` роутере, то у меня `инет` работать не будет.

Comment: В роутере не надо ничего изменять. Если у вас стоит роутер, то укажите 127.0.0.1 в свойствах вашего WiFi-соединения (или проводного, если в с роутером соединены кабелем)В настройках Acrylic ничего менять не надо - там уже прописан DNS-сервер [вот этого](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS) проекта.Если всё-же хотите поменять - ищите строку `PrimaryServerAddress=` и пропишите там DNS вашего провайдера или адрес роутера.

Comment: где именно указать? Я прилагаю скриншот настроек `Wi-Fi`-соединения, если я тут что-то изменю, то у меня слетит соединение.

Comment: Ставите галочку "Использовать следующие адреса DNS" серверов, и прописываете туда 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Настройки `mod_rewrite` можно писать не в главном файле, а в `.htaccess` в папке конкретного сайта    RewriteEngine on    RewriteBase /